# I've created a nested table. Is it possible to make a query on the table that really memorize the data of the nested table (STUDEN_NT_TAB)

Tags: oracle, nested-table

```
CREATE TYPE STUDENT_T AS OBJECT ( 
   NOME  VARCHAR2(30),
   COGNOME VARCHAR2(20),
   MATRICOLA INT(6));

CREATE TYPE STUDENT_NT IS TABLE OF STUDENT_T;

CREATE TABLE CORSO_DI_LAUREA (
   NOME_CORSO VARCHAR2(50),
   STUDENTI STUDENT_NT )
NESTED TABLE STUDENTI STORE AS STUDEN_NT_TAB;
```

Comment: I guess your title is translated from Italian(?); I'm not sure what you're trying to find. The storage used for the nested table? Or are you just trying to query the data from the nested table? Please edit your question to explain, format your code, and preferably show what you have tried and what issues you are having.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29749173/1509264 However the question is not clear so it is possible that you want to ask something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search%3Ftag%3Daccessing-nested-tables-elements.

From that page we can see that your query would be somthing on the order of:

```
select nome_corso from coroso_id_laurea, table(studenti)
```

I highly agree with what they say immediately after the example:

> "Finally, while you can store multiple values using nested tables, in
> the vast majority of cases you're better off using regular tables
> instead. This makes it easier to query and work with your data!"

I have done some experimentation with nested tables. For me they became a nightmare of complexity so I switched back to the standard relational model.